# How to apply color on text in Markdown

Tags: markdown

I want to use Markdown to store textual information. But quick googling says Markdown does not support color. Also Stack Overflow does not support color. Same as in case of GitHub markdown.

Is there any flavor of markdown that allows colored text?

Comment: I mean you can mix them with [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/README.html) for instance : `<span style="color:red"> *some emphasized markdown text*</span>`. If you are asking about native markdown handling of colors, I don't think it exists

Comment: [This answer](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/369#issuecomment-394483061) might be of some help as it was for me...

Comment: As noted in the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61637203/441757, you can get some amount of color into markdown docs — without resorting to HTML and CSS — by using color emoji. Of course that doesn’t work for all cases, but for example, if you had wanted to color the word **true** in green and the word **false** in red, you can instead just do, e.g.: ✅ **true** and ❌ **false**. So you still get a color indication/hint, but without needing to color the entire string of text.

Answer (score 996, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Markdown doesn't support color but you can inline HTML inside Markdown, e.g.:

```
<span style="color:blue">some *blue* text</span>.
```

**Longer answer**

As the original/official [syntax rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) state (emphasis added):

> Markdown’s syntax is intended for one purpose: to be used as a format for writing for the web.
>
> Markdown is not a replacement for HTML, or even close to it. Its syntax is very small, corresponding only to a very small subset of HTML tags. The idea is not to create a syntax that makes it easier to insert HTML tags. In my opinion, HTML tags are already easy to insert. The idea for Markdown is to make it easy to read, write, and edit prose. HTML is a publishing format; Markdown is a writing format. Thus, ***Markdown’s formatting syntax only addresses issues that can be conveyed in plain text***.
>
> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself.

As it is not a "publishing format," providing a way to color your text is out-of-scope for Markdown. That said, it is not impossible as you can include raw HTML (and HTML is a publishing format). For example, the following Markdown text (as suggested by @scoa in a comment):

```
Some Markdown text with <span style="color:blue">some *blue* text</span>.
```

Would result in the following HTML:

```
<p>Some Markdown text with <span style="color:blue">some <em>blue</em> text</span>.</p>
```

Now, StackOverflow (and probably GitHub) will strip the raw HTML out (as a security measure) so you lose the color here, but it should work on any standard Markdown implementation.

Another possibility is to use the non-standard Attribute Lists originally introduced by the [Markuru](http://maruku.rubyforge.org/proposal.html#attribute_lists) implementation of Markdown and later adopted by a [few](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/attr_list.html) [others](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#attribute-list-definitions) (there may be more, or slightly different implementations of the same idea, like [div and span attributes in pandoc](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#divs-and-spans)). In that case, you could assign a class to a paragraph or inline element, and then use CSS to define a color for a class. However, you absolutely must be using one of the few implementations which actually support the non-standard feature and your documents are no longer portable to other systems.

Comment: Thanks. With some more [reading](https://blog.codinghorror.com/standard-flavored-markdown/), Markdown is a specific language (like C, say) in a category that might be called *lightweight markup*.

Comment: Thank you. I wish I could post a fry swish dot gif here. your answer was so succinct, it was <span style="color:green"><i>tight</i></span> .

Answer (score 259):

When you want to use pure Markdown (without nested HTML), you can use [Emojis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) to draw attention to some fragment of the file, i.e. ⚠️**WARNING**⚠️, **IMPORTANT**❗ or **NEW**.

Comment: Here's a cheat sheet with markdown emoji codes, eg `:warning:` for a warning triangle: https://github.com/ikatyang/emoji-cheat-sheet  These work in a huge number of markdown dialects, including GitHub and Slack.

Comment: To use emoji on markdown in VSCode you will need to install one extension between [Markdown emoji](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.markdown-emoji) or [emojisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.emojisense)

Comment: @paolopazzo You can definitely use extensions if that's convenient for You, but extensions are not required. There are other options. like: 1) Copy & paste emojis from sites like [Emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/) or [Unicode Full Emoji List](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html), 2) On Windows you press Windows logo key + period key to enter emoji.

Comment: Yes, totally right, I taught that maybe could be a useful information for people reading your comment. With extension, on any OS, you just type :emoji_you_want: and you are done

Comment: Alternative is to copy the emoji and paste into Markdown directly. Seems to have worked for Sharepoint's version of Markdown! ⚠️ <- copied this directly into Markdown.

Answer (score 81):

I have started using Markdown to post some of my documents to an internal web site for in-house users.  It is an easy way to have a document shared but not able to be edited by the viewer.

So, this marking of text in color is “Great”. I have use several like this and works wonderful.

```
<span style="color:blue">some *This is Blue italic.* text</span>
```

Turns into *This is Blue italic.*

And

```
<span style="color:red">some **This is Red Bold.** text</span>
```

Turns into **This is Red Bold.**

I love the flexibility and ease of use.

Comment: This solution doesn't work in markdown files hosted on Github

Answer (score 74):

I like the idea of redefining existing tags if they're unused due to the fact that the text is cleaner, at the expense of existing tags.  The inline styling works but creates a lot of noise when reading the raw text.

Using VSCode I've found that custom single-letter tags, supported by a small `<style>` section at the top, works well with a minimum of noise, especially for spot colour, e.g.

```
<style>
r { color: Red }
o { color: Orange }
g { color: Green }
</style>

# TODOs:

- <r>TODO:</r> Important thing to do
- <o>TODO:</o> Less important thing to do
- <g>DONE:</g> Breath deeply and improve karma
```

My use-case is orgmode-ish in-app note taking during development but I guess it might work elsewhere?

Comment: Could this be used in an app like Obsidian?

Comment: Clean and clever.

Comment: Just tried this in a jupyter notebook Markdown cell and it didn't produce any colors. :-(

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the update!  I'm not currently a Jupyter user and haven't tested every markdown implementation.  One of the other answers may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 50):

While Markdown doesn't support color, if you don't need too many, you could always sacrifice some of the supported styles and redefine the related tag using CSS to make it color, and also remove the formatting, or not.

Example:

```
// resets
s { text-decoration:none; } //strike-through
em { font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; } //italic emphasis


// colors
s { color: green }
em { color: blue }
```

See also: [How to restyle em tag to be bold instead of italic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535836/how-to-restyle-em-tag-to-be-bold-instead-of-italic)

Then in your markdown text

```
~~This is green~~
_this is blue_
```

Answer (score 49):

As an alternative, whatever purpose colour serves in your text may be achieved with coloured Unicode characters, such as , U+1F534 'large red circle'.

For example, I use characters like this when I document wire colours, when hardware accompanies my software projects on GitHub.

```
 red: +5V
 orange: +3.3V
⚫ black: ground
⚪ white: ground (pull-down)
 purple: I2C signal
 green: clock signal
 yellow: WS2812 signal
 blue: resistor bridge (analogue) input
```

Maybe this would be useful for your documentation, too. You can copy and paste this example into your text, or websearch for strings like 'unicode purple square'. They're also considered emoji.

Comment: Very cool -- learned something not quite new, but totally forgotten. :-)

Answer (score 44):

This should be shorter:

```
<font color='red'>test blue color font</font>
```

Answer (score 24):

you can probably use the latex style:

```
$\color{color-code}{your-text-here}$
```

To keep the whitespace between words, you also need to include the tilde `~`.

Comment: Isn’t there a syntax confusion between `{\color{red}text}` and `\textcolor{red}{text}`, here? This works only by chance, and changes the color of what comes _after_ `{your-text-here}` as well. Tested right now with `$\color{red}{foo}bar$` on GitHub. Also, `~`-s are not just any spaces, they are non-breaking spaces, so long pieces of text may overflow or break in unexpected ways. All in all, something like `$\textsf{\textcolor{red}{Foo bar plop}}$` (combining suggestions from other users on this page) is significantly more robust and, arguably, more intuitive, IMHO.

Answer (score 21):

Now since May 2022, Github has LATEX to use on Markdown, you can use LATEX code to use some kind of color on your repos, like this examples:

### Basic

| Code | Appearing |
| --- | --- |
| `$${\color{red}Red}$$` | $${\color{red}Red}$$ |
| `$${\color{green}Green}$$` | $${\color{green}Green}$$ |
| `$${\color{lightgreen}Light \space Green}$$` | $${\color{lightgreen}Light \space Green}$$ |
| `$${\color{blue}Blue}$$` | $${\color{blue}Blue}$$ |
| `$${\color{lightblue}Light \space Blue}$$` | $${\color{lightblue}Light \space Blue}$$ |
| `$${\color{black}Black}$$` | $${\color{black}Black}$$ |
| `$${\color{white}White}$$` | $${\color{white}White}$$ |

### More than one color

- Code

```latex
$${\color{red}Welcome \space \color{lightblue}To \space \color{orange}Stackoverflow}$$
```

- Visualization

$${\color{red}Welcome \space \color{lightblue}To \space \color{orange}Stackoverflow}$$

- The view on Github:

[image: Visualization on Github]

- If you want to know more, [Github Blog](https://github.blog/2022-05-19-math-support-in-markdown/) explain the new support, and my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/F4NT0/444939156c34f399c0dfbcf0fe632bb7) if you want :)

Comment: Why it's italic? Can't be just a regular text

Comment: this is the standard font from KATEX on Github, but you can use some kind of fonts available on the documentation website from KATEX

Comment: Using `$ ... $` or `$$ ... $$` uses TeX math mode. You can try `$\textsf{\color{red}Red text}$`. `\textsf` stand for san-serif; `\textrm` can be used for roman and `\texttt` for typewriter. I also use `\large` inside the braces to get a larger font.

Comment: I find it quite confusing that this answer makes it sound like only `$$`, which is meant for centered formulas, works, while `$` is generally what we need instead. I wish the comment from @Jander got integrated into the answer itself, and the examples given in the table could then be drastically simplified (no need for `\space` anymore either).

Comment: @Jander Also worth noting that the slightly shorter `\text{…}` command exists (I think it picks up whichever font was the default outside of the math environment at the time).

Comment: @smerllo Without any `\text` command, it interprets the text as a formula, so as a big product of lots of one-letter math variables. This is not text _per se_, which explains the weird kerning, typically in “Stackoverflow” in the example of this answer (large gap between the _r_ and the _f_). Maths are in italics by default in LaTeX.

Answer (score 17):

Short story: links. Make use of something like:

```css
a[href='red'] {
    color: red;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="red">Look, ma! Red!</a>
```

(HTML above for demonstration purposes)

And in your md source:

`[Look, ma! Red!](red)`

Comment: Clever! Lots of potential here for arbitrary styling.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks for all answers in this thread.

I with agree that, the end purpose is to emphasize and distinguish texts. So here is the integration of answers that I learnt from this thread, with personal preferences (check them out by pasting in MD editor):

| style | markdown |
| --- | --- |
| ⚫ ⚪ | same |
| ✅ true and ❌false | same |
| underline | <u>underline</u> |
| ~~stroke~~ | ~~stroke~~ |
| *italic* | *italic* |
| ==highlight== | ==highlight== |
| **bold** | **bold ** |
| `red color` | `red color` |
| blue color | <a >blue color</a> |
| other color | <font color=#0fb503>other color</font> |

Comment: Color works for nowadays

Answer (score 9):

In `Jekyll` I was able to add some color or other styles to a **bold** element (should work with all other elements as well).

I started the "styling" with `{:` and end it `}`. There is no space allowed between element and curly bracket!

```
**My Bold Text, in red color.**{: style="color: red; opacity: 0.80;" }
```

Will be translated to html:

```html
<strong style="color: red; opacity: 0.80;">My Bold Text, in red color.</strong>
```

Answer (score 7):

Seems that [kramdown](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/documentation.html) supports colors in some form.

Kramdown [allows inline html](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#html-elements-1):

```
This is <span style="color: red">written in red</span>.
```

Also it has another syntax for [including css classes inline](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#inline-attributes):

```
This is *red*{: style="color: red"}.
```

[This](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/07/19/markdown-kramdown-tips-and-tricks/#classes-ids-and-attributes) page further explains how GitLab utilizes more compact way to apply css classes in Kramdown:

> Applying `blue` class to text:
>
> ```
> This is a paragraph that for some reason we want blue.
> {: .blue}
> ```
>
> Applying `blue` class to headings:
>
> ```
> #### A blue heading
> {: .blue}
> ```
>
> Applying two classes:
>
> ```
> A blue and bold paragraph.
> {: .blue .bold}
> ```
>
> Applying ids:
>
> ```
> #### A blue heading
> {: .blue #blue-h}
> ```
>
> This produces:
>
> ```
> <h4 class="blue" id="blue-h">A blue heading</h4>
> ```

There is a lot of other stuff explained at [above link](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/07/19/markdown-kramdown-tips-and-tricks/#classes-ids-and-attributes). You may need to check.

Also, as other answer said, Kramdown is also the [default markdown renderer behind Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/#kramdown). So if you are authoring anything on github pages, above functionality might be available out of the box.

Answer (score 5):

This works in the note-taking Joplin:

```
<span style="color:red">text in red</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Run the following in zeppelin paragraph**

%md
`###  <span style="color:red">text</span>`

Answer (score 3):

I've had success with

```
<span class="someclass"></span>
```

Caveat : the class must already exist on the site.

Answer (score 3):

Put in the RMarkdown header this command

```
header-includes: \usepackage{xcolor}
```

and then use this command to color your text

```
\textcolor{green}{Text is green!}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a Hading in Jupyter Notebook with any given color.

[image]

Will appear like heading in the notebook, if you don't use ## in the beginning will appear like a normal text in the given color

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Pain in the butt.

Markdown to PDF via pandoc worked for me only when using:

```
---
header-includes: 
                 \usepackage{xcolor}
                 \definecolor{alizarin}{rgb}{0.82, 0.1, 0.26}
---

\color{alizarin}The overarching aim \color{black} of this project is
```

"The overarching aim" in red - the rest in black. Font stays the same and no trouble with spaces.

Exporting to odt or docx - no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Color
Markdown doesn’t allow you to change the color of text, but if your Markdown processor supports HTML, you can use the  HTML tag. The color attribute allows you to specify the font color using a color’s name or the hexadecimal #RRGGBB code.

```
<font color="red">This text is red!</font>
```

The  HTML tag is technically supported but officially deprecated, which means it works for now but you’re not supposed to be using it. Unfortunately, there’s not another pure HTML alternative. You could try using one of the CSS alternatives. Not all Markdown applications provide CSS support, but if the one you’re using does, here’s an alternative to the  tag:

```
<p style="color:blue">Make this text blue.</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use the below syntax to get the BOLD & Font Color as Red

```
__`A`__
```

Comment: Use where exactly?