# Markdown text color within a code block

Tags: markdown

I frequently need to paste a code section into a Markdown document and then I want to change some color in the text.

For example:

````
This is a code sample:
```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```
````

How can I set the text string "Hello World!" to the color red? I wish to use it as a code block since I don't want to reformat it to Markdown style.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply Color in markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465557/how-to-apply-color-in-markdown)

Comment: You may want to look at "syntax highlighting". There are a lot of options out there and providing tool/library recommendations is off-topic, but that should be a good search term to get you started.

Comment: @mb21 I would not necessarily consider this a duplicate. It is quite common to add color to code blocks through syntax highlighting. Of course, if the OP only wants to color a single string and not apply highlighting to the entire code block, then yes this would be a duplicate. Unfortunately, we don't have enough information to know for sure.

Answer (score 21):

You can't put color on it.

Try putting C like this:

````
```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```
````

It will make your text seems as code.