# Disable zebra striping in Github table markdown

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

By default Tables in Github Markdown are rendered with alternate rows highlighted (zebra striped). What is the markdown to disable this feature? The [Github markdown documentation for tables](https://help.github.com/articles/organizing-information-with-tables/) does not describe how this is done.

For example, this table has row striping:

[image]

The corresponding markdown is:

```
Key|Value
---|-----
A|B
C|D
E|F
G|H
```

This question is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35465557/41410) which talks about applying colors in markdown. This question relates specifically to the alternating row highlighting in tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply Color in markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465557/how-to-apply-color-in-markdown)

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with GitHub's markdown.

Comment: Looking at the css, there is only one rule that sets `.markdown-body table tr:nth-child(2n){
    background-color:#f6f8fa
}` and nothing else that could possibly overwrite it. So I'd say it's a no-go.

Answer (score 14):

It's not possible with CSS, but there is a workaround. Just add an empty row between your rows.

```
<tr></tr>
```

Comment: So hacky, but I love it.

Comment: 1 trillion IQ..

Comment: Can you give an example? If I put `<tr></tr>` in my markdown formatted table, the table outputs until `<tr>` and then no output.

Comment: I'd love an example too. I'm not sure where to insert `<tr></tr>`. When I add the `tr` between rows it cuts out all of the rows below the `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

As you both asked for a example, here is snippet from a table i am constructing, note the `<tr></tr>`, this disables zebra striping.

```
| Description | YAML Path | Type | Values | Example |
| :---------- | :-------- | :--- | :----- | :------ |
| Absolute path to existing media | general/library | String | N/A | `library_path: '/media'` <tr></tr> |
| Daemonised mode | general/daemon_mode | String | 'foreground'\|'background' | `daemon_mode: 'foreground'` <tr></tr> |
```