# Make a word ([link_name]) inside a github markdown header be written with a smaller font

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

I tried:

```
# This is a header <span style="font-size:small;">[link_name]</span>
```

and got this:

## This is a header link_name

but I want link_name to be at a smaller font.

At vs code this works, but at github it doesn't.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not seem to be supported, for the same reason mentioned in "[How to apply color in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35465557/6309)"

> Markdown’s formatting syntax only addresses issues that can be conveyed in plain text.

Within an header (level  1: `#`), you can have only "plain  text".

Comment: Accepted. But, when more than one # are prepended to the header, the font gets smaller, so maybe there is a get-around somehow. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Thanasis I don't see the font getting smaller around link name. As see the font getting smaller at the header level, since level 3 is smaller than level 2 which is smaller than level 1 header.