# Coloring table rows in Azure Wiki

Tags: azure-devops, html-table, yaml, markdown, azure-devops-wiki

How can I create colored rows in table in [Azure Devops Wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-create-repo?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)? I want to create something like below

```css
.table-striped th {
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #bfff00 !important;
  color: #191919;
}

.table-striped tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: #4287f5;
}
```

```html
 <div>
   <table class="table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
   </table>
 </div>
```

The main way of creating tables in Azure Wiki is Markdown table, and from what I found is that Markdown [does not support color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35485694/911419). Maybe there is any trick?

From [Azure Wiki Syntax Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops) I found out that HTML tags and YAML tables are also supported, but everything that I was able to achieve is coloring via `span` tag inside markdown:

```
<span style="background-color: red">57065</span>|<span style="background-color: red">4560</span>|<span style="background-color: red">I AM TABLE ROW</span>
```

and that looks ugly.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve full-fledged coloring?

Comment: Please consider tagging this `azure-devops-wiki`. I would have done it but there is a five tag limit and I did not want to remove any of your tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with inline styling. Here I made an example:

```
<table style="border:ridge 4px red">
  <tr style="background-color:blue;color:white;" id="ROW1">
    <td style="border:ridge 4px red" >Cell 1.1</td>
    <td style="border:ridge 4px red">Cell 1.2</td>
    <td style="border:ridge 4px red">Cell 1.3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:yellow;color:green;" id="ROW2">
    <td style="border:ridge 4px red">Cell 2.1</td>
    <td style="border:ridge 4px red">Cell 2.2</td>
    <td style="border:ridge 4px red">Cell 2.3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It looks like that in Azure DevOps Wiki:

[image]

I hope it will help you, but.. I strongly encourage to keep markdown simple. Please take a look at this stack discussion: [Color in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465557/how-to-apply-color-in-markdown)

Comment: Great, enjoy :)

Comment: For what it's worth I discourage mixing HTML with markdown. It violates [Wiki's Simple and Mundane principles](http://wiki.c2.com/?WikiDesignPrinciples) and it may be impossible for others to maintain. It may also present future portability problems  (which may or may not be important to you).